# C# File.AppendAllText path parameter change itself

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I'm trying to use System.IO.File function like AppendAllText(string path, string content)

I have a project located on my Desktop (test project) and a file located on my desktop too

and here is my main function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"‪C:\Users\Joevin\Desktop\MyFile.txt";
        string message = "Hello World !";
        File.AppendAllText(path, message);
    }
```

Based on what I have seen on the [C# Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-5.0) it should append my message on my txt file

But if I run my project, I have this error:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The syntax of the file, directory or volume
> name is incorrect.:
> 'C:\Users\Joevin\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\net5.0\‪C:\Users\Joevin\Desktop\MyFile.txt''

So, it's appeared that when the function AppendAllText is called the path that I give is now the path of the executable generated + my path stored in the "path" variable.

And i have the same error with others System.IO.FIle function that take a path as parameter

*I feel that the problem is on my way to give the path to the function but I don't know how.*

Can someone explain me why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Have a look at the output for Path.GetFullPath(path) which is ultimately what gets called on your path. I suspect you have some weird controlcode character in your path string that is causing that function not to detect you are using an absolute path. Try typing  the paths value from scratch without copy/pasting it.

Comment: The code you've posted contains a U+202A character (left-to-right embedding) after the opening double quote. Remove that and it'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet for you answer ! It's strange that Visual Studio can’t catch this kind of issue …

Answer (score 2):

You probably copied the value for your path variable from somewhere and it contains (in the current codepage) not visible characters. It causes Path.GetFullPath to interpret your path as a relative path.

Since you copied your actual code in your question I copied your line into notepad++ and changed the codepage to ansi and it reveals the hidden characters

@"â€ªC:\Users\Joevin\Desktop\MyFile.txt";

Comment: Thank you for your respond and it was indeed the problem ….
I got used to copy the path of the file from the property of the file (Property/Security/Object Name)
It seems not to be a good idea to use it with code. 

It’s strange that Visual Studio can't check this kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

Path seems to be wrong in your case.

You can use the below code to get the desktop path.

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);



string path = Path.Combine(desktopPath, “MyFileName.txt”);
```

And then use the [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) method to get the complete file path and pass to the `AppendAllText` method.

Comment: Yeah, my path was wrong (bad format). I just rewrote it manually and it fix my issue
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Joevin you should use the path as I have mentioned in the answer. It will reduce the typing mistakes and will work on Linux as well.

Comment: This path was for a test project, the path i use on my project is not on my desktop but thanks for the suggestion.